# want to shrink cordova App display output

Tags: android, css, nexus-4

I created a web-app, with a target of a Nexus 4 phone in mind, intended to be used in landscape orientation.
It looks fine using chrome.  But when I then used that HTML/CSS to create a Cordova App, the display is way too big for the phone.  I have tried many things suggested by many people to no avail.
As an example, if I have the following div defined:

```
#content {
    border:             thin ;
    border-style:       solid ;
    width:              960px ;
    height:             475px ;
}
```

and as a web-app, the border fits nicely in the display of the Nexus 4 using chrome.  But I have to reduce that 960px down to around 570px to get it to fit when it is a App installed via cordova.  I am doing a 'fixed' position for all my divs inside that #content div.  There is only 1 target device that this App will get used on - I don't care about any other devices.  (Yes, I really want to do that).  I don't want scrolling.

I tried setting the *target-densitydpi=medium-dpi"* as suggested in [Phonegap/Cordova App Shrink too small on high resolution device like Samsung Galaxy S4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435651/phonegap-cordova-app-shrink-too-small-on-high-resolution-device-like-samsung-gal)
and [Phonegap Application text and layout too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194940/phonegap-application-text-and-layout-too-small)

I've tried setting *initial-scale=1.0* like many people suggest.
I've tried 1.5 and 2.0 which makes it even bigger, but 0.5 does not make it smaller.
I tried adding
*preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true"*
to my config.xml as suggested by [PhoneGap: Scaling down a webpage with viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579078/phonegap-scaling-down-a-webpage-with-viewport)

While I have tried many combinations, my basic viewport definition is:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,
        initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1,
        width=device-width, height=device-height,
        target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
```

Nothing has worked for me.

I have no idea how this stuff works and I have very little experience with front-end and mobile App technologies.  I see no relationship between the advertised hardware devices resolution and what I see on a web-app, and what I see on a native App.  I don't know why they would behave differently on the same device with the same CSS.

Any suggestions and/or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution at [Android 4.1 viewport scaling ( setInitialScale, meta initial-scale not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636515/android-4-1-viewport-scaling-setinitialscale-meta-initial-scale-not-working)
(although there is a missing opening curly bracket).

By using:

```
function customScaleThisScreen() {
    var contentWidth = document.body.scrollWidth, 
        windowWidth = window.innerWidth, 
        newScale = windowWidth / contentWidth;
    document.body.style.zoom = newScale;
}
```

and setting my viewport to:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,
        initial-scale=0.6, maximum-scale=0.6, minimum-scale=0.6,
        width=device-width, height=device-height,
        target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
```

it now fits within my Nexus 4 screen.
Although the height (in landscape mode) comes a bit short of what I ideally wanted, the entire display is shown.  It uses up about 90% of my available height which I can live with.

I also found that setting:

```
<preference name="EnablEnableViewportScale" value="false" />
```

in config.xml does nothing - whether I set it to true or false.
Before, I was able to scale upwards of 1.0 (such as 2 and 4), but not below 1.0, no matter what EnableViewportScale was set to.  But the above code solved this.
I am running Android 4.4.4